# how to naviagate in react native between componets

Tags: android, react-native

i was previosly woeking on react js   & i am new to react native  i am trying to naviage betwwen componets in my app
i am using **react navigation** i dont know whethere this is the easyest way

i have app.js and Sign.js

**app.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {Provider as PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {Avatar, Card, Title, Paragraph} from 'react-native-paper';
import {Image} from 'react-native';

import {Button} from 'react-native';

function Dashbord({navigation}) {
  const LeftContent = props => <Avatar.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />;
  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
     
      
      <Card
        style={styles.main2}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigation.navigate('Sign')}>
        <Image
          source={require('./assets/images/mother.png')}
          style={{
            width: 80,
            marginLeft: 90,
            marginTop: 0,
            justifyContent: 'center',

            height: 80,
            textAlign: 'center',
          }}
        />
        <Text
          style={{
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 20,
            fontFamily: 'Poppins-ExtraBold',
          }}>
          i am a mother
        </Text>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}



const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            options={{headerShown: false}}
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Dashbord" component={Dashbord} />
          <Stack.Screen name="sign" component={sign} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

sign.js is inside of components folder i dont know how i can access it
**Sign.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default function Sign(navigation) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.prheight}>
      <View style={styles.prheight}>
        <Text style={styles.r}>dada</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonw}>
        <Button color="#7743DB" title="Lets Go" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

the error ` i am getting is propery sign doesnot exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little change in `HomeScreen` function: `HomeScreen(navigation)` to `HomeScreen({ navigation })`

If you want use `HomeScreen(navigation)`, just change `onPress` function:
`onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dashbord')}` to `onPress={() => navigation.navigation.navigate('Dashbord')}`